# HTML parsing with SwiftUI

Tags: html, ios, swift, swiftui

In my project, I parse HTML json api to my app from an article website with this code

```
do {
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(dataPolimats.content.rendered)
    let elements: Elements = try doc.select("*")
    
    var viewModels: [ElementViewModel] = []
    for element in elements {
        if let tagName = try? element.tagName() {
            switch tagName {
            case "img":
                if let src = try? element.attr("src") {
                    viewModels.append(ImageViewModel(src: src))
                }
                
            case "a":
            if let href = try? element.attr("href"), let text = try? element.text() {
                    viewModels.append(LinkViewModel(label: text, destination: href))
                }
                
            case "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6":
                if let text = try? element.text() {
                    viewModels.append(TitleViewModel(text: text))
                }
            case "p":
                if let text = try? element.text() {
                    viewModels.append(ParagraphViewModel(text: text))
                }
                
            case "ul":
                if let listItems = try? element.select("li") {
                    for listItem in listItems {
                        if let text = try? listItem.text() {
                            viewModels.append(ListItemViewModel(text: text))
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            case "iframe":
                if let src = try? element.attr("src") {
                    viewModels.append(YouTubeViewModel(embedURL: src))
                }
            default:
                break
            }
```

However, the problem is that in some of the articles in the website, have some paragraphs that includes links and written with red color like this: [a paragraph from an article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0YAQ.png)
How can I get links from paragraphs and show like in the photo?
These are the my view models for paragraph and links to add view:

```
struct ParagraphViewModel: ElementViewModel {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let text: String
    var view: AnyView {
        AnyView(
            HStack {
                
                Text(text)
                    .font(.custom("Roboto-Regular", size: 17))
                    .lineSpacing(10)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                
                Spacer()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

```
struct LinkViewModel: ElementViewModel {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let label: String
    let destination: String
    
    var view: AnyView {
        AnyView(
            Link(destination: URL(string: destination)!) {
                Text(label)
                    .foregroundStyle(.realRed)
                    .underline()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried different view models and if statements in HTML parsing but I could not even near the solution. I only get links from paragraphs and put them below paragraphs.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `AnyView` shouldn't be used like this. Search `@ViewBuilder` and `some View` and watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for more info